# How to keep calendar icon on first field

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form for start date and end date using datepicker.

```
<input name="dateBegin" id="start" type="text" title="<?php echo date("m/d/Y"); ?>" style="position: relative; z-index: 10;" />
<input name="dateEnd" id="end" type="text" title="<?php echo date("m/d/Y"); ?>" style="position: relative; z-index: 10;" />
```

When I use them "as-is" I get an calendar icon on both fields.

When I attach the following code (below) to the form (it sets end date with the value of start date) the calendar icon for the start date disappears.

How can I get the calendar icon to stick even with my additional code?

```
<script>
$('#start').datepicker({
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
 $("#end").val(dateText);
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does that code override another `datepicker()` call? Try just setting the `onSelect` option instead of re-initializing the datepicker.

Comment: Jason - could you explain that a bit more - where is the re-initialazation?

Comment: What do you mean with as is "calendar icon"? Like this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger? Elaborate your question please

Comment: Edward - perhaps an image might help: ![calendar-ok](http://best-4-web.com/calendar-ok.jpg)
 With the additional code added 
![calendar-misssing](http://best-4-web.com/calendar-missing.jpg) - essentially it displays the same as the example you linked to.

Comment: Lisa for the future to tag people you must type @ before the name, ore no notification will be received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have gone through the code that you have given here and made some modifications :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#start').datepicker({
 showOn: "button",
 buttonImage: "http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif",
 buttonImageOnly: true , 
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
 $("#start").val(dateText);
}
});

$('#end').datepicker({
 showOn: "button",
 buttonImage: "http://keith-wood.name/img/calendar.gif",
 buttonImageOnly: true , 
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
 $("#end").val(dateText);
}
});
});
```

Try out this [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXa7h/3/).

In case, you want to keep both the fields side by side, yo can try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/XXa7h/5/

**EDIT:** Okay, so , the solution below will set the start date in both places.

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/XXa7h/7/

You can see that, i have still kept the line : `$("#end").val(dateText);` uncommented. In case, you do not want the user to select date in the `End` field then just comment out or remove the line. Hope this is good enough ! Cheers !

Comment: Dark Knight - what you set up is what I need, however when a value is entered into the start date it needs to be copied into the end date field. Getting that value to copy across is what blocks the icon for the start date.

Comment: Alright, give me a few moments, i will cook up something for you.

Comment: @LisaWhiteBarrett-Handley : See My EDIT section in the answered post above .

Comment: BRILLIANT!  The is EXACTLY what I need - no more disappearing calendar icon - YEAY!  Thank you Dark Knight :-)

Comment: @LisaWhiteBarrett-Handley  : Sure np, happy to help, don't forget to upvote and accept by clicking the tick mark.